# checkbox form gives list in rails, how to use jquery function to iterate through list in controller?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with checkboxes that gathers the facebook ids of users. I want to use those ids to send them app requests.

When my form is submitted, it generates a list of facebook ids and it runs a method `sendrequest`.

Here is my form in the view home.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag sendrequest_path do%>
        <%=check_box_tag "friendids[]", 12345 %>
        <%=check_box_tag "friendids[]", 67890 %>
        <%=submit_tag "send requests"%>
    <% end %>
```

I'd like to somehow get the below javascript to run when the `sendrequest` form is submitted. However the caveat is that it must iterate through the friendsid[] list.

```
 <script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    frictionlessRequests: true
  });

  function sendRequestToRecipients() {
    var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      to:
```

Specifically here it should iterate through params[:friendids]. Facebook allows multiple requests as long as it is comma separated so 
`to: "12345,67890"` would work in this example. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery, then you can do the following:

First, we assign an id to the form

```
<%= form_tag sendrequest_path, id: 'send-request-form' do %>
```

Then we observe the submit event of that form and get a list of all checked checkboxes. Then

```
$('#send-request-form').submit(function() {
  var friendIds = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').map(function() { return this.value })
  // then you can use friendIds.join(',') as the comma separated list of friend ids
  sendRequestToRecipients(friendIds.joins(',')) 
});

function sendRequestToRecipients(ids) {
   // use ids in this function
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However I'm getting an error that friendIds doesn't have a join method. (I replaced your joins with join but still to no avail). What type of variable is friendIds?

Comment: nevermind I see what was wrong. you need a .get() at the end of your var friendIds function. Thanks for your help!